# Ruby zerofill a string

Tags: ruby, printf, ruby-1.9.2

Formating an Integer to be filled with zeros is easy in Ruby:

```
sprintf( "%010d", 345 ) #=> "0000000345"
```

But when I try to fill a String with zeros I can't find an easy solution:

```
sprintf( "%010d", "12AD" ) #=> ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "12AD"
sprintf( "%010s", "12AD" ) #=> "      12AD"
```

I would like to obtain:

```
sprintf( "%010s", "12AD" ) #=> "00000012AD"
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can use [`rjust`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-rjust) or [`ljust`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-ljust).

```
>> "12AD".rjust(10, '0')
#=> "00000012AD"
```

Comment: How not!! Obviously easier than sprintf !